# How to generate binary from MSP430 assembler with correct jumps?

Tags: assembly, simulation, microcontroller, msp430

I'm programming a MSP430 in C language as a simulation of real microcontroller (or emulator if you want). When I prepare **test.s** file for MSP430:

```
    .text
.global main
    .type   main, @function

main:
    mov #8,r4;
    add r5,r5;    // r5 = 0
    jz l1;
    add r6,r6;    // r6 = 0
    jz l2;
    push r6;     // for break purpose


l1:
    mov #0x1234,r8; 
    push  r10;

l2:
    mov #0x5678,r9;
    push r11;
```

I got such verification (by MSP430) file **test.lst**:

```
test.elf:   file format elf32-msp430

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   34 42           mov #8, r4      ;r2 As==11
   2:   05 55           rla r5          ;
   4:   00 24           jz  $+2          ;abs 0x6
   6:   06 56           rla r6          ;
   8:   00 24           jz  $+2          ;abs 0xa
   a:   06 12           push    r6      ;

0000000c <l1>:
   c:   38 40 34 12     mov #4660,  r8  ;#0x1234
  10:   0a 12           push    r10     ;

00000012 <l2>:
  12:   39 40 78 56     mov #22136, r9  ;#0x5678
  16:   0b 12           push    r11     ;
```

The problem is that JUMPS (i.e. JZ) are never going to happen. Whatever Z flag is set before JZ, code is moving through JZ. My emulation of JZ is:

1. Read Code (16 bits) and get offset (10 bits LSB)
2. Check Z flag (0 or 1)
3. If Z = 0, move to next section of Code (PC++)
4. Else, set PC = PC + 2*offset

In binary file, generated by MSP430, the offset value is exactly 0 (should be more than 0 to move PC into another Code section).

**How to make Jumps work correctly?** Or maybe generation of binary file is broken?

Comment: While some call C the "assembler of high-level languages", this is about true Assembler. Do not add unrelated tags!

Comment: @Olaf, nope, I do this in C language. Assembler is only used for preparing binary input files (which could be a cause of the problem).

Comment: You only show Assembler output. C is not relevant for this. At most, it is a matter of the compiler.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand something, but it's not clear why do you think the ZERO bit should be set (as in the comment `r5=0`)? The instruction "add r5, r5" simply adds r5 to itself, it does not set it zero in the general case.

Comment: As as side note, you do know of https://github.com/mspsim/mspsim, do you?

Comment: @kfx: It does very well. Please see the MSP430 instruction set. Note that is quite typical for many CPUs.

Comment: Too little information. The assembler shown: is that from ready-linked code or the object file? Also show what the debugger's disassembly says. That is the most useful information.

Comment: @kfx I want to create processor in C (with input and output), this site is worthless for my objectives

Comment: @Olaf in that case `mspsim` is broken. However, I also checked the instruction set and did not see any relevant comments, so that seems doubtful.

Comment: @kfx: 1) OP did not state which compiler/assembler he uses. 2) Nor did he say if the file has been relocated or not, which might make a difference. 3) And to see which flags the `ADD` instruction changes - thus if a `JZ` is usefull or not, you just have to see the instruction description in any MSP430 family user's guide.

Comment: @kfx http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau049f/slau049f.pdf at 85 page. And from page #40: " Zero bit. This bit is set when the result of a byte or word  operation is 0 and cleared when the result is not 0."

Comment: @Olaf, I use TI-GCC (http://www.ti.com/tool/msp430-gcc-opensource)

Comment: @Olaf you may want to detract your first comment in light of ziom's link unless you have conflicting information.

Comment: @kfx Why would I? That is clearly not about C.

Comment: @Olaf perhaps we're misunderstanding each another. The claim that "add r5, r5" sets the register to zero (which you supported) looks misleading to me, you should back it up with a reference or remove it.

Comment: @kfx: The claim was it sets the `ZERO` flag in the status register according to the outcome of the operation. And that is very true and quite common for most CPU architectures. I **did** back it up; please read my comments again! It is not my fault if you are not able to find the documentation I mentioned - TI's website is quite well-structured. If you still insist, it is youir's to prove me wrong.

Comment: @Olaf ok, so you actually agree with my first comment. Makes sense now. BTW, `mspsim` is not a compiler or an assembler.

Comment: @kfx: I don't see how I could. Maybe it is badly worded, but you state that `add` will not set the flag(s). On second reading, I'm not sure what you mean with "general case", though. The instructions always sets/updates the flag - either to `0` or `1`. The MSP430 does not have ALU instructions which do not update any flag.

Answer (score 2):

Your `test.elf` file actually is an object file, so it still contains unresolved relocations.

After assembling and linking this file (with the C compiler, to get the C startup code that calls `main`), the jumps are correct:

```
$ msp430-gcc -mmcu=msp430f5529 -minrt -o test.elf test.s
$ msp430-objdump -d test.elf
...
0000454e <main>:
    454e:   34 42           mov #8,     r4  ;r2 As==11
    4550:   05 55           rla r5          ;
    4552:   03 24           jz  $+8         ;abs 0x455a
    4554:   06 56           rla r6          ;
    4556:   04 24           jz  $+10        ;abs 0x4560
    4558:   06 12           push        r6  ;

0000455a <l1>:
    455a:   38 40 34 12     mov #4660,  r8  ;#0x1234
    455e:   0a 12           push        r10 ;

00004560 <l2>:
    4560:   39 40 78 56     mov #22136, r9  ;#0x5678
    4564:   0b 12           push        r11 ;
...
```

It is possible to generate a binary from this:

```
$ msp430-objcopy -O binary test.elf test.bin
```

However, the resulting file is not very useful because it does not contain its start address. You would be better off creating (and then using in your simulator) an [Intel hex file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX):

```
$ msp430-objcopy -O ihex test.elf test.ihex
```

Comment: how to make, with this method, test.s into test.bin (with correct jump values)?

Comment: Updated; but a .bin file would get the absolute addresses wrong.

Comment: then how to implement input data binary with right addresses?

Comment: A plain binary file does not (cannot) contain ist start address. Which is why you should not use this format.